Why is SQLAlchemy / Pydantic auto-loading relations only sometimes and not always?
I have a weird issue in my FastAPI-based application using SQLAlchemy and Pydantic with a Postgres-Database.
A User-Model contains two different 1-to-Many-relationships. For unknown reasons, the first relationship is always automatically loaded although it shouldn't. The second relationship works as expected.
My Models:
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid7, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner", lazy="select")
    datastreams = relationship("DataStream", back_populates="owner", lazy="select")


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid7, unique=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.id"))

    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="items")


class DataStream(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data_stream"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid7, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    type = Column(data_stream_type_enum, nullable=False)  # Enum for type: 'folder' or 'stream'
    parent_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("data_stream.id"), nullable=True)  # Self-referencing foreign key
    owner_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.id"))

    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="datastreams")

    # Self-referential relationship for parent/child hierarchy
    parent = relationship("DataStream", remote_side=[id], backref="children")

My CRUD layer contains these two functions among others:
def get_user(db: Session, user_id: UUID):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()

def get_users(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.User).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()

The API-Endpoint will respond with the following Schema:
from pydantic import BaseModel


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str


class User(UserBase):
    id: UUID
    is_active: bool
    items: list[Item] = []
    dataStreams: list[DataStream] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

The Endpoints look like this:
@router.get("/", response_model=list[user_schemas.User])
def read_users(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    users = crud.get_users(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return users


@router.get("/{user_id}", response_model=user_schemas.User)
def read_user(user_id: UUID, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user(db, user_id=user_id)
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    return db_user

The API-Response contains always the fully loaded Items-relation, but not the DataStreams-relation, although they exists and are associated with the same owner-id.
[
  {
    "email": “xxx@yyy”,
    "id": "066fbcc7-61ff-7359-8000-440710dffadc",
    "is_active": true,
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "string",
        "description": "string",
        "id": "066fc123-237d-73e4-8000-bc6b98e36cfa",
        "owner_id": "066fbcc7-61ff-7359-8000-440710dffadc"
      },
      {
        "title": "string",
        "description": "string",
        "id": "066fc149-10bc-7569-8000-a629cd4d7e52",
        "owner_id": "066fbcc7-61ff-7359-8000-440710dffadc"
      }
    ],
    "dataStreams": []
  }
]

My Questions are:

Why are Items automatically loaded and DataStreams not?
How can I avoid that Items will get loaded automatically?


The DataStream relationship on User is named datastreams but in the pydantic model it's dataStreams. The names must be identical, or you must apply an alias.

"How can I avoid that Items will get loaded automatically?" -> what are the criteria for this decision? Do you want to avoid setting the values on the pydantic model, or just not output them when serialising?

I found a weird solution:
In order to NOT retrieve nested objects of one-2-many relations, I wrote another Schema that does not contain such attributes:
class User(UserBase):
    id: UUID
    is_active: bool

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class UserComplex(User):
    items: list[Item] = []
    datastreams: List["DataStream"] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

With this approach, I am going to have two different endpoints:

one that contains only basic attributes for a flat response
one that contains the relationships

Remarkable also is the comment from @snakecharmerb that I wrote one time "dataStreams" and one time "datastreams". Python is not stopping me from doing so, but it had implications for Pydantic.

There's no intrinsic connection between the Pydantic model and the SQLAlchemy model. When the Pydantic model is passed and object it looks for attributes with names that exactly match those of the attributes declared on the Pydantic model.
